# How to do mathematical operations in same column on different rows in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the questions suggests, is there a way to do mathematical operations on the same column except different rows?

Example.

```
Table A:                
    X   Y   Time    New_time
0   aaa bbb 5         3
1   aaa bbb 2         1
2   aaa bbb 1         null
```

i want to find the difference in time for each row. So row 0 would have new_time as 3min. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: microsoft SQLserver is DBMS. bc before DBeaver I was using microsoft sql server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` analytic function introduced in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Times]
    (
      [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                 NOT NULL ,
      [X] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL ,
      [Y] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL ,
      [Time] [INT] NOT NULL
    ); 


INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Times]
        ( X, Y, [Time] )
VALUES  ( 'aaa', 'bbb', 5 ),
        ( 'aaa', 'bbb', 2 ),
        ( 'aaa', 'bbb', 1 );

SELECT  * ,
        New_Time = [Time] - ( LEAD([Time]) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) )
FROM    [Times];
```

And the output will be:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to not specify the actual time as you have in the values part because this difference will be applied to millions of rows in the database. sorry beginner at this.

Comment: RustyShackleford values in insert query? I dont get your question

Comment: Yes sorry the insert query is there a way to specify to go over all the cells in the column rather than inputting time from each column into the INSERT query.

Comment: What is your source for this column?

Comment: You only need to use the last bit of Yared's response, ie `SELECT  * ,
        New_Time = [Time] - ( LEAD([Time]) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) )
FROM    [Times];`  The first two bits is just for creating test data.

Comment: You can use migration queries if values  for the column found in another table: 

Insert Into dbo.Times(X,Y,[Time])
Select 'aaa' X, 'bbb' Y, [TIME_VALUE] From ANOTHER_TABLE

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Table1 table(id int, x varchar(10), y varchar(10), [time] int)
insert into @Table1 values
(0,'aaa', 'bbb', 5)
,(1,'aaa', 'bbb', 2)
,(2,'aaa', 'bbb', 1)

select *,
 [time] - LEAD([Time]) over(order by id)  as NewTime
from @Table1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, how could I apply your function to millions of rows in the 'value' part?

Comment: Actually, you need to apply the select statement to your table. The values part provided to initialize the sample table. if you have millions of rows, you probably need to load it using something like BULK INSERT.